# Using sed / awk to process file with stanza format

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file in stanza format. Example of the file are as below.

```
id_1:
        id=241
        pgrp=staff
        groups=staff
        home=/home/id_1
        shell=/usr/bin/ks
id_2:
        id=242
        pgrp=staff
        groups=staff
        home=/home/id_2
        shell=/usr/bin/ks
```

How do I use sed or awk to process it and return only the id name, id and groups in a single line and tab delimited format? e.g.:

```
id_1        241     staff
id_2        242     staff
```

Comment: does any of the fields other than id name, can contain `:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an awk solution:

*translate.awk*

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
  if(match($1, /[^=]:[ ]*$/)){
    id_=$1
    sub(/:/,"",id_)
  }
  if(match($1,/id=/)){
    split($1,p,"=")
    id=p[2]
  }
  if(match($1,/groups=/)){
    split($1,p,"=")
    print id_," ",id," ",p[2]
  }
}
```

Execute it either by:

```
chmod +x translated.awk
./translated.awk data.txt
```

or

```
awk -f translated.awk data.txt
```

For completeness, here comes a shortened version:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
$1 ~ /[^=]:[ ]*$/ {sub(/:/,"",$1);printf $1" ";FS="="}
$1 ~ /id/         {printf $2" "}
$1 ~ /groups/     {print $2}
```

Comment: Is not it too much complicated for a rather simple job?

Comment: Do you have simpler *working* solution? What do you mean with complicated?

Comment: Hi, what if some of the id does not have the 'id_' format? I have tried `if(match($1, /^[A-Za-z0-9_.]/)){` on line 3 but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: but the `:` is guaranteed?

Comment: Hi hek2mgl. Yes it is guaranteed. Thanks.

Comment: Have updated the first regex. Its now matching lines which contain no `=` and have a `:` and optional whitespace at the end. Note that I've used the *longer* syntax in my example to make the code more readable. You can shorten it like Servé Laurijssen has done

Comment: I wanted to mention explicit `sub` `split` can be dropped with proper `FS`. Also no need to store the variables, we can just keep on printing as we get something. Basically what Servé Laurijssen has done. But you have already explained that yourself :)

Comment: Hi hek2mgl. Thanks. I'm able to customize your answer to fit other requirements as well.

Comment: Ok, fine! :) Have added a shorter version as well.

Answer (score 2):

with awk:

```
BEGIN { FS="="}

$1 ~ /id_/ { printf("%s", $1) }

$1 ~ /id/ && $1 !~ /_/ { printf("\t%s", $2) }

$1 ~ /groups/ { printf("\t%s\n", $2) }
```

Comment: This leaves the `:` after the ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed 'N;N;N;N;N;y/=\n/  /' data.txt | awk '{print $1,$3,$7}'
```

Comment: This leaves the `:` after the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one-liner approach by setting `RS`:

```
awk 'NR>1{print "id_"++i,$3,$7}' RS='id_[0-9]+:' FS='[=\n]' OFS='\t' file
id_1    241     staff
id_2    242     staff
```

Requires `GNU awk` and assumes the IDs are in increasing order starting at 1.

If the ordering of the ID's is arbitrary:

```
awk '!/shell/&&NR>1{gsub(/:/,"",$1);print "id_"$1,$3,$5}' RS='id_' FS='[=\n]' OFS='\t' file
id_1    241     staff
id_2    242     staff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"=" '/id_/{split($0,a,":");}/id=/{i=$2}/groups/{printf a[1]"\t"i"\t"$2"\n"}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
id_1:
        id=241
        pgrp=staff
        groups=staff
        home=/home/id_1
        shell=/usr/bin/ks
id_2:
        id=242
        pgrp=staff
        groups=staff
        home=/home/id_2
        shell=/usr/bin/ks
> awk -F"=" '/id_/{split($0,a,":");}/id=/{i=$2}/groups/{printf a[1]"\t"i"\t"$2"\n"}' temp
id_1    241     staff
id_2    242     staff
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/^[^ :]+:/{N;N;N;s/:.*id=(\S+).*groups=(\S+).*/\t\1\t\2/p}' file
```

Look for a line holding an `id` then get the next 3 lines and re-arrange the output.